# How do I add user's avatar in embed title? discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

Here is my code example.

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
  test = discord.Embed(
        title=f"{ctx.author.avatar_url}",
        #skip
    )

    await ctx.send(embed=test)
```

[I am trying to make it like this, but it's not working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FnX8.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Discord.py 2.0 `discord.Member.avatar_url` has been changed to `discord.Member.avatar.url`. So the solutions won't work without this small change.

So, (editing loloTester's code):

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    test = discord.Embed()
    test.set_author(name="title", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar.url)
    await ctx.send(embed=test)
```

Also, note that `avatar` is only set when the user has set a custom avatar.
If you want to have a url to the avatar, regardless of whenever it's custom or not, use `display_avatar`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `title` attribute set [`author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.author) attribute using [`set_author()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.set_author) method. Like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    test = discord.Embed()
    test.set_author(name="title", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=test)
```

Comment: Ohhhhh it's that simple, ty for the help.

Comment: If this helped, you should accept this answer for others to see that this problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the picture is in the `embed.thumbnail` and in `embed.author.image`, so you have to set these two:

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    test = discord.Embed(title=f"Your embed title in the picture you attached it's Eggspert Player but doesn't have to be")
    test.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    test.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=test)
```

---

**References**:

- [embed.set_author](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed.set_author)
- [embed.set_thumbnail](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed.set_thumbnail)
- [member.avatar_url](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.avatar_url)